# using system.resetPassword() throws UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION in apex flex queue

Tags: customer-portal, user, passwords

Here's an excerpt from the debug log

> 19:01:57.287 (3403054287150372)|SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[298]|System.resetPassword(Id, Boolean)
>   19:01:57.287 (3403054287498523)|DML_BEGIN|[298]|Op:resetPassword|Type:User|Rows:1
>   19:01:57.290 (3403054290491653)|EXCEPTION_THROWN|[298]|System.UnexpectedException: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1950334240-14043 (-1480005366)
>   19:01:57.290 (3403054290509933)|DML_END|[298]
>   19:01:57.290 (3403054290599486)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[298]|System.resetPassword(Id, Boolean)
>   19:01:57.290 (3403054290668069)|FATAL_ERROR|System.UnexpectedException: UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1950334240-14043 (-1480005366)

and here's the code...

```
public class createUser implements Queueable{
    private User u = new User();
    //constructor
    public createUser(User createdUser){
        this.u = createdUser;
    }
    public void execute(QueueableContext context){
        insert u;
        system.resetPassword(u.Id, true);
    }
}
```

I have a unit test that runs just fine. I get the error when executing a functional test in a sandbox.

Comment: Contact support. There's not much *we* can do about this.

Comment: Thanks, fox. I have contacted support. I was just wondering if anyone else had a similar experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never got a solid answer from SF Support, but I did find a workaround... Here's what the code looks like now.

```
public class myOuterClass{

    //do some things..
    ...

    public class createUser implements Queueable{       //Queueable Class to avoid Mixed DML
        private User u = new User();                    //Needs a User to create (should NOT have a record ID!)
        public createUser(User createdUser){            //constructor, handles input parameter
            this.u = createdUser;                       // "u" is visible to Class now.
        }
        public void execute(QueueableContext context){  //Mandatory Execute method
            insert u;                                   //insert the User (won't work if there is a record ID!)
            system.debug(u);                            
            //system.resetPassword(u.Id, true);         //This line causes an UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION: SoOoO....
            resetmyKVHPassword(u.Id);                   //send the email in an @future method!
        }
    }

    @future static void resetmyKVHPassword(Id uId){     //Asynch method to reset password
        system.resetPassword(uId, true);                //since we apparently can't do it from within the queueable execute method!
    }
}
```

A *better* implementation would probably be Queueuable that invokes another Queueable rather than invoking an @future method.